# How to automate report delivery in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I have a report in SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) that I'd like to schedule to run automatically as an email.  I'd like the report to be attached as Excel file.
According to the [Microsoft overview](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/reporting-services.aspx) this should be possible.

> **Report delivery**. SQL Server Reporting Services supports both on-demand (pull) and event-based (push) delivery of reports. Users can view reports in a Web-based format or in e-mail.

However I can't find any information on how to actually do this.  Does anyone know what tools should be used or where there is a good tutorial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you browse to the report in your reporting services site you should see a tab for Subscriptions.  That's where you'd specify the recipients and delivery methods for automated delivery.

Here's a [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160334.aspx) that describes the process.

Comment: Thanks Cori.  I found out that the Workgroup Edition license that we're using doesn't support email delivery.

Answer (score 2):

I spotted this good youtube link on this topic which helped me:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO0Y_IxdE8w

Basically the steps (SQL server 2012) are:

Have the Web SSRS folder (in Internet Explorer browser) containing the report (or report link) showing, 
Hover mouse over the report, this mouse hover action then highlights the report in yellow outline border and offers a dropdown on the righthand side, click on the down arrow to open the dropdown and get list of options ..
One option is "manage", choose this option.

[image]

Down the left hand side of screen are offered :

Properties

Parameters

Subscriptions

Processing Options

Cache Refresh Options

Report History

Security

Choose the "Subscriptions" option here.

[image]

You can then Edit existing subscriptions.. or add a New Subscription .. e.g. as per this screen print

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL- RD Application for Dynamic schedules

Comment: Does this support Express Edition ? Nothing visible on that on their website.

Answer (score 1):

At first set the e-mail at Report Server Configuration Manager, then from your SSRS web browser click on the report and then subscription and give the recipient mail id's and the subject name followed by the mail message. Select the **Render Format** for the attachment type, set the time and date, that's all!

Regards,
Pratik Prakash