# Generate SQL Server reports automatically and pdf in vb.net

Tags: pdf, reporting-services

I need to generate automated periodic SSRS report, pdf and save in a specific folder.
Please advise how to perform this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can setup SSRS Subscriptions which allow you to do what you ask, some links:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872783.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx

[How to automate report delivery in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278297/how-to-automate-report-delivery-in-ssrs)